Python Object in Another Class's init
Today I found strange behavior in Python. I don't know how to describe but I will try. (I hope code will explain.)
Let's say I have 2 classes and they are related (A and B). When I am creating B, I want to point a variable to A.
class A:
    varA = 0

class B:
    a = None
    varB = 0
    def __init__(self, a=A()):
        self.a = a

This is working well.
I can reach to b.a.varA without a problem.
But when I create a new B() object, it will automatically reference to first B->A
b1 = B()
b1.a.varA = 1
print("b1.a.varA:", b1.a.varA)  # <-- b1.a.varA: 1 no problem

b2 = B()
b2.a.varA = 2
print("b2.a.varA:", b2.a.varA)  # <-- b2.a.varA: 2 no problem

print("b1.a.varA:", b1.a.varA)  # <-- b1.a.varA: 1 THIS IS THE PROBLEM.

I changed b2.a.varA but b1.a.varA is also changed.
Python not creating a new A object every time I created B object. All B.A's are the same.
All I want to do is, create a new A that completely on different location at memory.
I can't define __init__ as
def __init__(self):
    self.a = A()

because I might send predefined A to B.

That's what happens in Python when you use a mutable object as default parameter value.
